# I need to connect my front-end Javascript code to my sever-side NodeJS code. How do I do this?

Tags: client-server

We are very new to programming and have a simple question. We are developing a very simple Google search app that searches strings on Google using client-server communication. We have a simple subset of Javascript here:

```
 var firstName = some_string
 var lastName = some_string
 var googleSearch = firstName + lastName;
 googleSearch = JSON.stringify(googleSearch);
```

We need to link this code to our NodeJS code to do the actual searching.

```
 var google = require('google');
 google.resultsPerPage = 25;
 var nextCounter = 0;

 google(googleSearch, function(err,res) { // Note googleSearch is from
                                          // the frontend Javascript code
                                          // that we want to pull the data from.
     if (err console.error(err)
     var link = res.links[0];
     console.log(link.href);
     var myLink = link.href;


 })
```

**We want to take the data from the** `googleSearch` **variable from our front-end code and utilize it in our server-side code. Then we want to display the data from** `myLink` **, which is in our server-side code, back into our front-end code.**

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make an Ajax request from your front end to your server.

If you use jquery, you can do something like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: YOUR_SERVER_URL+"/getData",
data: {
  "google_search": googleSearch,
},
method: "GET",
//use data type json if your server returns json
dataType: "json",
success: function(result) {
  console.log("data fetched Successfully");
  //result is the data your server returned.
  console.log(result);
},
error: function() {
console.log("Something went wrong, data could not be fetched");
}
});
```

On your server side if you are using Express with Node, 
you can return JSON by doing something like this:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/getData', function(req, res, next) {
            var google = require('google');
            google.resultsPerPage = 25;
            var nextCounter = 0;
            //getting query data that you passed from front end
            var googleSearch = req.query.google_search;
            google(googleSearch, function(err, res) {
                    if (err console.error(err) var link = res.links[0]; console.log(link.href);
                        var myLink = link.href;
                    })
                //sending json data as response
                res.json(myLink);
            });
```

If you are using localhost, then your server url will be something like "https://localhost:5000".